# What are the essential steps to create a SHINY app that references a database?

Tags: r, shiny, odbc

I've consulted many Stack articles and Rstudio pages, and can't determine why my SHINY app, which references an ODBC database, works locally but not when it's placed on my SHINY server (free version).

I've tried using the `pool` package, but it does not help. For example, when I run the [pool example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-basics.html) it functions fine from RStudio, but not when I try to access it via the web.  **In contrast,** if I make an app that uses the preloaded R datasets (such as mtcars or iris), my apps work on the web.

What are the essential steps to create a SHINY app, **which references databases**, to work on the web?

My app uses a `ui`  `server` and `global` file; each is shown below.

## ui

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2);library(stringr);library(shiny);library(DT)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Online Events Reporter"),
    fluidRow(
    column(3,
           h4("Select Your Event:"),
           selectInput("eventSelect","Event Name",eventchoice)  ) ),    
fluidRow(column(8,
                plotOutput("evalPlot"))),
    hr(),
dataTableOutput("table")

 ) )
```

## server

```
library(dplyr);library(DBI);library(DT)
library(ggplot2);library(stringr);library(shiny);library(zoo)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  # event data contains only responses from one of the eval quetsions
  eventdata <-reactive({     
    subset(temp, temp$title2==input$eventSelect)  })

  comments2 <-reactive({     
subset(comments, comments$title2==input$eventSelect)  })

  output$evalPlot <- renderPlot({
# generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
ggplot(data=eventdata(),
       mapping=aes(x=eventdata()$title2, fill=factor(eventdata()$Rating) ), 
       position = "fill") +
  geom_bar()+theme_minimal()+ggtitle("Summary of Evaluation Responses")

  })

  output$table = renderDataTable(comments2(), 
                                 options=list(
                               pageLength=8)
                             )

}
```

## global

```
library(DBI);library(dplyr);library(zoo)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "tablename", timeout = 10)
gfdata<-dbGetQuery(con,'SELECT * FROM `tablename`.`namehere` ')
onlineSesh<-gfdata[gfdata$form_id==11,]  # all works fine

# create options for ui drop-down menu
eventchoice<-onlineSesh %>% 
  dplyr::filter(meta_key=="2") %>%  
  select(meta_value)  %>% unique() %>% unlist(use.names = F)

# sloppy munging in here but it works...
t<-onlineSesh
x<-onlineSesh[onlineSesh$meta_key=='3', c( "meta_value","entry_id")]  # dates 
colnames(x)[1]<-"sessiondate"
t<-merge(t, x,by="entry_id")
colnames(t)[1]<-"WorkshopID"
eitems<-c("Strongly Agree", "Agree","Slightly Agree","Slightly Disagree","Disagree","Strongly Disagree")

# when meta_key==2, title
t$title<-ifelse(t$meta_key=='2',t$meta_value,NA)
t$title2<-na.locf(t$title,na.rm = FALSE) # we need the event title on all relevant records!!!
t$Rating<-factor(t$meta_value, levels=c("Strongly Agree", "Agree","Slightly Agree", 
                                    "Slightly Disagree","Disagree","Strongly Disagree"),ordered =     T)

# keep records that contain  answers; 
temp<-base::subset(t, meta_value %in% eitems) # this file utilized by SHINY


comments<-subset(t, t$meta_key=="19") # another file utilized by SHINY
comments<-comments %>% select(title2,meta_value,sessiondate)
```

Comment: Where does your `ODBC` database live? What kind of database is it exactly?

Comment: It is a SQL database (formed from a WordPress GravityForms plugin) that lives on a server separate from the SHINY server.

Comment: @MrFlick Any further thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a Microsoft SQLServer database? Is that database open to the public? Often there are security measures to prevent certain machines from accessing database directly. And normally ODBC connections are set up on the host machine which you would not have access to on a free hosted shiny server. I still don't understand exactly how you are connecting with this code.